# Serve static file if it exists else create it

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, httphandler

How can I make StaticFile handler serve only files that actually exist and make others go to asp.net mvc pipeline or custom http handler.

```
1) GET /images/file.jpg
  exists => serve it (StaticFile handler / as efficiently as possible)

2) GET /images/file_640x480.jpg
  1. request (doesn't exist)
  * load file.jpg
  * resize
  * save as file_640x480.jpg
  => serve from memory

  following requests 
  => should use 1) because the file is now there
```

It's trivial with `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />`
but I guess that is more of a workaround than a real solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this code but something on these lines should work

```
public FilePathResult GetFile(string name)
{
    FileInfo info = new FileInfo(name);
    if (!info.Exists)
    {
        //Code to load the original file, resize and save would go here
    }

    return File(name, "text/plain");
}
```